# Pygame Mouse Event Position Issue

Tags: python, pygame, mouseevent

I want to obtain coordinates of mouse position at the time when the mouse button is pressed. I'm using the following code to try to achieve that:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = event.pos
```

My problem is when I move the mouse just after clicking, `event.pos` gives me the new cursor position instead of the coordinates of where I actually clicked. How do I set `mouse_pos` to the actual coordinates of the click?

Comment: Is move mouse just after clicking different then dragging in your context

Comment: If you use `mouse_pos = event.pos`, `mouse_pos` will contain the actual coordinates of the click. Maybe you overwrite it elsewhere in your code?

Comment: @udhy Yes, I release the mouse button and then move.

Comment: @sloth No, I didn't find it overwritten elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Try making a small program and run this code, does this still gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

Although this thread was asked 4 months ago if your still looking for the answer here it is...

In your loop you are using the wrong command to get the mouse position. Instead of using this...

```
mouse_pos = event.pos
```

Use this...

```
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

This command will grab the current mouse location when called, and return it as a tuple like this (x,y).

I hope this helps you with your issue.

Comment: `event.pos` is the mouse position.